# JQUERY UI TABS - PreventDefault jumping

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

i've read a lot of questions and answers about that behavior but can't find a solution working in my particular case.

I'm using JQUERY UI TABS and i'm sending back the id's of the anchor in the url so the opened tab stay opened on page refresh. I would like to disable anchor jumping when loading a tab so the top of the website is always visible when navigating trought tabs. Here is my code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $(".tabs").tabs({
        activate: function (event, ui) {
            window.location.hash = ui.newPanel.attr('id');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The focus of an anchor is default browser behaviour, window.scrollTo(0,0) should do the trick.

Comment: How can i mark this as answered ?

Comment: @axel.michel has to post it as answer to mark it as answer

Comment: @Thierry, you can't  - it is just a comment - this has been already answered a few times.

Comment: Ok ! Thanks anyway ! I'm new to Jquery and Scripting so i don't always know where to place the code... Soz... Have a Good Day